# Convertir RTF a Texto Plano o HTML Javascript

Tags: javascript, rtf

Tengo un Erp que me envía desde la base de datos en formato JSON un rtf:

```
"{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\deff0\\nouicompat{\\fonttbl{\\f0\\fnil\\fcharset0 Arial;}}\r\n{\\colortbl ;\\red0\\green0\\blue128;}\r\n{\\*\\generator Riched20 10.0.19041}\\viewkind4\\uc1 \r\n\\pard\\cf1\\b\\fs18\\lang3082 primera observaci\\'f3n\\par\r\n\\par\r\nsegunda observaci\\'f3n\\par\r\n\\par\r\ntercera observaci\\'f3n\\par\r\n}\r\n\u0000"
```

Tengo está función pero no me hace los saltos de linea ni me pone los acentos, tildes bien

```
function convertToPlain(rtf) {
      // rtf = rtf.replace(/\\par[d]?/g, "");
      rtf = rtf
         .replace(/\{\*?\\[^{}]+}|[{}]|\\\n?[A-Za-z]+\n?(?:-?\d+)?[ ]?/g, "")
         .trim();
      return rtf;
      // return rtf.replace(/\\'[0-9a-zA-Z]{2}/g, "").trim();
   }
```

Lo que me devuelve:

```
primera observaci\'f3n segunda observaci\'f3n tercera observaci\'f3n
```

A mi me da igual si es texto plano o HTML, la idea en general es poder visualizarlo correctamente..

Muchas gracias

Comment: as intentando un `return rtf.replaceAll("\\'f3","ó");` aunque lo mejor seria ver todas las palabras con acentos y crear un diccionario ejemplo `dicc= {"\\'f3" : "ó" }` para todos....

Comment: Lo pensé pero se me hacía imposible con tantos casos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En el formato RTF se solían usar secuencias para guardar caracteres especiales; de acuerdo a [esta tabla](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/rtf-pocket-guide/9781449302047/ch04.html), se puede ver que lo que se guarda es una marca `\'` seguida del valor hexadecimal del caracter correspondiente, con valores desde `00` (decimal 0; caracter de control que no debe usarse) hasta `ff` (decimal 255, ÿ).

Solo se necesita una expresión regular para extraer las secuencias y remplazarlas por el caracter correspondiente:

```js
let rtf = "{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\deff0\\nouicompat{\\fonttbl{\\f0\\fnil\\fcharset0 Arial;}}\r\n{\\colortbl ;\\red0\\green0\\blue128;}\r\n{\\*\\generator Riched20 10.0.19041}\\viewkind4\\uc1 \r\n\\pard\\cf1\\b\\fs18\\lang3082 primera observaci\\'f3n\\par\r\n\\par\r\nsegunda observaci\\'f3n\\par\r\n\\par\r\ntercera observaci\\'f3n\\par\r\n}\r\n\u0000";

// Función para encontrar secuencias de caracteres especiales
function parseSpecial(rtf) {
   // Encontrar todas las secuencias \'xx
   let matches = rtf.match(/\\'[a-f0-9]{2}/g);
   // Eliminar duplicados en el arreglo
   let special = [... new Set(matches)];
   // Recorrer para remplazar
   special.forEach(hex => {
       // Convertir de hexadecimal a decimal, eliminando primero la marca \'
       let dec = parseInt(hex.replace("\\'", ''), 16);
       // Remplazar secuencia por caracter correspondiente
       rtf = rtf.replaceAll(hex, String.fromCharCode(dec));
   });
   return rtf;
}
function convertToPlain(rtf) {
    // Interpretar contenido original
    rtf = rtf.replace(/\\par[d]?/g, "");
    rtf = rtf.replace(/\{\*?\\[^{}]+}|[{}]|\\\n?[A-Za-z]+\n?(?:-?\d+)?[ ]?/g, "").trim();
    // Buscar secuencias de caracteres especiales y devolver
    return parseSpecial(rtf);
}

console.log(convertToPlain(rtf));
```

Expresión regular: `/\\'[a-f0-9]{2}/g`

- `/` Al inicio y al final para delimitar la expresión
- `\\` Diagonal invertida, aparece doble porque es caracter de escape y necesita escaparse a sí misma
- `'` Comilla simple o apóstrofe
- `[a-f0-9]` Buscará solo caracteres válidos en números hexadecimales
- `{2}` Solo dos caracteres de los especificados entre corchetes
- `g` Indica que se trata de una búsqueda global

Comment: Perfecto, esto va muy bien, Sigue sin hacerme los saltos de línea pero entiendo que es la forma de como lo introduzco al parrafo de html (element.textContent = textoPlano), lo he probado con innerHTML y sigue sin hacerme los saltos de linea, alguna otra idea para poder insertarlo?

Comment: Remplaza los saltos de línea `\n` por `<br>`

Comment: Eso era lo que pensaba, al final remplazo los \n por <br> e inserto el texto con elemento.innerHTML y funciona perfectamente, muchas gracias